# How do I get the hostname of the server end of a Windows pipe, from a file handle to the client end?

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I want the reverse of WinAPI's [GetNamedPipeClientComputerName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getnamedpipeclientcomputernamea).

Using WinAPI, preferably. (I'm trying to avoid having to talk to .NET, make expensive system() calls to Powershell, or write all the infrastructure necessary to consume WMI/MI or COM.)

Edit: Yes, I know if I control both ends and it's duplex I can write logic to have the server tell me its hostname. Let's skip that hack.

Comment: What does *"reverse"* mean to you?

Comment: @IInspectable Assume I have a handle to the client end of a named pipe instance, obtained via `CreateFile("\\\\otherhost\\pipe\\pipename",...)`. How can I query that handle in a way that will result in the string `"otherhost"`?

Comment: I don't know whether that works, but have a look at [GetFileInformationByHandleEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex), and query for the `FileNameInfo` to get a [FILE_NAME_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-file_name_info) back.

Comment: Sadly, GetFileInformationByHandleEx's doc pages says "This handle should not be a pipe handle.". Additionally, even on file types for which it works, it only writes to FILE_NAME_INFO the "file" part of the path (in this case, "pipename"), not the device part.

Comment: @KeithRussell Why can't you simply remember the path you give to `CreateFile()` and parse it as needed? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh, holy cow, I did *not* mean to upvote that (IMO unhelpful) comment. X-|

Comment: @KeithRussell There seems no such WINAPI. Could you sharing the reason of retrieving hostname of the server from a pipe handle?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Ask your colleagues who wrote `FILE_NAME_INFO` why anyone would want to recover a file path from a file handle, and I’m guessing you’ll get the same answer I’d give you here.

Comment: @KeithRussell For example, for a symbolic link named "C:\tmp\mydir" that points to "D:\yourdir", the final path would be "D:\yourdir". Refer to [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks).